# Fill an actionsheet with an array

Tags: iphone

I have an actionsheet popup in my iphone application.  I would like to fill it with strings from an array instead of predetermined values.

I can't find anything online to do this!  Perhaps actionsheet isn't the right thing to use?

Right now this is what I'm using to build it:

```
roomspopup = [ [ UIActionSheet alloc ]  
                  initWithTitle: alertname  
                  delegate: self 
                  cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" 
                  destructiveButtonTitle: nil 
                  otherButtonTitles: @"Kitchen", "Dining Room", nil ];
```

But, instead of "Kitchen" and "Dining Room" I'd like it to fill in from an array.  The size of the array (i.e. the number of rooms) is not a fixed number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it in one line.  You'll have to call `initWithTitle` with an empty set of buttons, and then add your other buttons with loop using [`addButtonWithTitle:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/addButtonWithTitle:).

Answer (score 14):

@JimTrell

The way to fix that would be to init the UIActionSheet without the cancel button and add this cancel button after you added your other buttons.

First init the sheet with a bunch of nil's:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose" 
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Then loop through your array with `addButtonWithTitle:` and finally add the cancel button and set its index:

```
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:[yourArray count]];
```

Comment: More generally: `[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:[actionSheet numberOfButtons] - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

I can set up the cancel button at bottom by using this code:

```
anActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change A/C" delegate:self
  cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [arraylist count]; i++)    
  [anActionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[arraylist objectAtIndex:i]];

anActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [arraylist count];    
[anActionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```

Comment: anActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex=[arraylist count]; is the main point.
U will hv to declare it after looping so that cancel button is set up after all other buttons.